# Error while linking : linker script

Tags: linker-scripts

What does this error means?

> **section .data can't be allocated in segment 2**

This is for a bare metal GCC cross toolchain for Xtensa. I feel that this has nothing to do with the segment size.

Comment: Be more clear with your codes...

Comment: What does this error mean in general?

Answer (score 0):

The SECTIONS command tells the linker how to map input sections into output sections, and how to place the output sections in memory.
The format of the SECTIONS command is:

```
 SECTIONS
 {
   sections-command
   sections-command
   ...
 }
```

We can include explicit bytes of data in an output section by using BYTE, SHORT, LONG, QUAD, or SQUAD as an output section command.

> When using a 64 bit host or target, QUAD and SQUAD are the same; they
>   both store an 8 byte, or 64 bit, value. When both host and target are
>   32 bits, an expression is computed as 32 bits. In this case QUAD
>   stores a 32 bit value zero extended to 64 bits, and SQUAD stores a 32
>   bit value sign extended to 64 bits.

*If the object file format of the output file has an explicit endianness, which is the normal case, the value will be stored in that endianness.* When the object file format does not have an explicit endianness, as is true of, *for example*, S-records, the value will be stored in the endianness of the first input object file.

Note—**these commands only work inside a section description and not between them, so the following will produce an error from the linker:**

```
 SECTIONS { .text : { *(.text) } LONG(1) .data : { *(.data) } }
```

whereas this will work:

```
 SECTIONS { .text : { *(.text) ; LONG(1) } .data : { *(.data) } }
```

I hope now you can work out with your error!!!